# Python- Convert groupby return value into desired data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert data frame A

Dataframe A

```
App_ID  Review_Rating   Grouping
 4        3              Low
13        2              Low
13        2              Low
20        2              Low
20        4              High
8         1              Low
8         1              Low
8         1              Low
15        4              High
7         3              Low
4         3              Low
4         3              Low
4         3              Low
4         3              Low
4         5              High
7         5              High
15        3              Low
```

into Dataframe B (which contains grouping value into percentage):

```
App_ID    Percentage of Grouping
          Low     High
4         75      25
13        100     0
20        33      67
8         100     0
15        42.8    57.14
7         37.5    62.5
```

Here is my code:

```
dataframeB=(dataframeA.groupby(['App_ID','Grouping'])['Review_Rating'].count()/dataframeA.groupby('App_ID')['Review_Rating'].count()*100).reset_index()
```

However it does not give desired output. Output of my code:

```
App_ID   Grouping   Review_Rating
4        Low        75
4        High       25
13       Low        100
13       High       0
20       Low        33
20       High       67
8        Low        100
8        High       0
15       Low        42.8
15       High       57.14
7        Low        37.5
7        High       62.5
```

Looking for your help to rectify the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)?

Comment: If instead of the `reset_index()` you added `.unstack(1).fillna(0)` you'd get your desired output. Also, I think you mean `.sum()` instead of `.count()` as your aggregation function

Answer (score 2):

Very close to `pivot` problem , but you need normalized . Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.App_ID,df.Grouping,df.Review_Rating,aggfunc='sum',normalize ='index')*100
Out[90]: 
Grouping       High         Low
App_ID                         
4         25.000000   75.000000
7         62.500000   37.500000
8          0.000000  100.000000
13         0.000000  100.000000
15        57.142857   42.857143
20        66.666667   33.333333
```